# Why subsetting with a numeric key doesn't work with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table with two numeric rows, one of which is set to key. I would like to subset my `data.table` by numeric key value, but it doesn't seem to work. When I convert it to character, it works.

Could you help me to understand why is that? I am using data.table 1.8.6.

Thanks a bunch. Here is the test code:

```
> ID <-c(rep(210, 9), rep(3917,6))
> Count <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
> x <- data.table(ID, Count)
> 
> # numeric key doesn't work with i argument
> setkey(ID)
 [1]  210  210  210  210  210  210  210  210  210 3917 3917 3917 3917 3917 3917
> x[210,list(ID, Count)]
   ID Count
1: NA    NA
> 
> # create character key
> x$charID <- as.character(x$ID)
> setkey(x, charID)
> x["210",list(ID, Count)]
   charID  ID Count
1:    210 210     1
2:    210 210     1
3:    210 210     0
4:    210 210     1
5:    210 210     1
6:    210 210     1
7:    210 210     1
8:    210 210     1
9:    210 210     1
```

Comment: Is ID numeric or factor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to send the numeric key within a data.table. This  is done easily using `J`. Or in a list

Note that you need to specify the data.table when setting the key
eg

```
setkey(x, ID)
x[J(210)]
    ID Count
1: 210     1
2: 210     1
3: 210     0
4: 210     1
5: 210     1
6: 210     1
7: 210     1
8: 210     1
9: 210     1
```

or

```
x[list(210)]
    ID Count
1: 210     1
2: 210     1
3: 210     0
4: 210     1
5: 210     1
6: 210     1
7: 210     1
8: 210     1
9: 210     1
```

Comment: Not sure why this is -- I have a key which is numeric, with negative values. I try to use the syntax J(-1) and it doesn't work, but the list(-1) does work. May be of use to someone :)

Answer (score 5):

When you ask R for `x[210, ]` it is looking for the 210th row in `x`.
If `x` had 210+ rows, it would return that value (albeit not the row you were intending). Since there is no 210th row, it gives you NA.

When you instead ask for `x['210', ]`, it is looking for the row in `x` labeled `'210'`

---

Try this to see the differences:

```
 vec <- LETTERS[1:9]
 names(vec) <- c(11:18, 1)
```

Now compare:

```
 vec[[11]]
 vec[['11']]


 vec[[1]]
 vec[['1']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Ricardo. Could you advise on how I can make it work? If I still use numeric key `ID`, then there will be type mismatch

Comment: I think this probably will do a vector search, which is not what I want. In fact, I used data.table here because I want to use binary search functionality of it.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there a reason you don't want to simply use `x$id <- as.character(x$id)`?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Your solution would work fine for me. I have to set/reset keys quite often (just to utilize binary search for my large dataset) to create new variables, so I would rather have a more convenient way to do it. After all, I think the point of numeric key index is to make subsetting  using it.

Comment: I think this is really strange.... I was able to subset by a numerical index (in my own example) for key==.1 and key==.2, but then it failed on key==.3.

Comment: Changing the key to character did make the code work in all examples, but it's disconcerting that it has this inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @geneorama, what you are seeing is an issue with floating point. Not specific to R or data.table, but you can search for `[r] floating point` and you will see tons of detailed expalanations